# How can I find door hardware to match the fitment of my vintage hardware?

Tags: doors, lock

I want to replace the lock but want to keep using all the existing holes in the door.

Photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9wld.jpg

On the side, the only engravings are "PAT APR 17 06, OTHER PAT PEND.". I guess these are patent-related details.

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It would be a good idea to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how the site operates. Your lockset looks like an antique and probably has value as one. I doubt you'll determine the maker but someone on our site may know.

Comment: Just the lock or the whole handle/knob set? The lock cylinder is easily changed and a locksmith may be able to repair the workings if the knob/catch is not working properly in these kind of old locks. Good luck on finding a replacement. There may be one out there, and it would be better if the body was removed, the brand will most likely be on the body of the latchset.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeImprovement/comments/fiqsus/newbie_question_how_can_i_tell_which_brandmodel/

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above it will be very difficult to identify the maker of your old lockset. However. you shouldn't have to if you're simply going to replace it.   It should be relatively easy to find a replacement lockset that will fit this door without too much adjusting of the door. However, you're probably not going to know until you remove the old lockset and search out replacement sets. Take the old lockset with you when looking for a new one. With this type of replacement I think that's a better way to find what will work instead of shopping on-line.
There are always some adjustments that need to be made, particularly to mortise in the lockset stile and the strike plate. The wood looks to be in relatively good shape so you might be able to get away with minor refurbishment such as, if necessary, filling in the old screw holes. I like to use wood splinters or toothpicks and wood glue. That's if you're lucky. You will probably have to relocate the strikeplate which may require some wood repair around the original site of the plate. Good luck.

Comment: You could try shopping at some antique door handle places if you want to keep the look.+

Comment: Updated here: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeImprovement/comments/fiqsus/newbie_question_how_can_i_tell_which_brandmodel/

Answer (score 0):

I’d try Restoration Hardware stores, especially the ones that have antique hardware (doors, lights, etc.) in their store. You can send a picture and they’ll try to match it up.

I’d also try Habitat for Humanity retail outlets.

If that doesn’t work, try Emtek.com. They have a terrible website , but great customer service. Give them a call.